# python https requests failing with TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

We are using `requests.post` for sending https request to one of the server which has `SNI` enabled.

```
resp = requests.post(registration_url,
                         data=json.dumps(request_payload),
                         headers=headers
                         )
```

Our python service which uses python 2.7.5 version, giving below error for this request.

```
[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:618)
```

In the same machine, if we open python 2.7.5 cli and invoke
the above `requests.post` then request is going through and getting response back. Not getting any tls error.

We checked the tcpdump of ssl handshake for both the requests, and found that

1. Request sent from the service doesn't have SNI populated in it
2. Request sent from the python cli has SNI populated in it..

How can we debug, why `SNI` is not getting populated when request is invoked from the service?

Comment: Python versions below 2.7.9 has problems with SSL connections. There are some distribution which patched the SSL changes into earlier versions though. In general: It sounds like it's time to upgrade, at least to the latest version of 2.7, better to a recent version of Python 3.

Comment: Given that it works from cli but not from service I would argue that either there is (slightly) different code or URL used or that there are different versions of Python and/or relevant libraries installed and the cli is using the newer version while the service is using the older one. Maybe there are newer version installed locally for the user running the cli.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeah thought so, just to verify this, printed openssl version, python version, http headers, url from both service and cli, and all of these are same. I recently started working on python, so was not sure how could i dig this more to find out why these 2 are behaving differently. any pointers would be helpful thanks.

Comment: @user198234: load the relevant modules you need for your program an then check from where they are loaded by printing [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules). Check the differences in this output when running from cli and running as service.